# Build C++ project with Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I have an C++ project that i want to generate .so from it to use in Android application in future. I am using android ndk r16b. The structure of android project (with C++ support) is:

`-app
---.externalNativeBuild
---build
---jni
---openssl-armeabi-v7a
---src
------main
----------cpp
-------------mylib
------------------Folder1
-------------------------source1.cpp
-------------------------source1.h
------------------Folder2
------------------------source2.cpp
-------------------------source2.h
------------------Folder3
-------------------------source3.cpp
-------------------------source3.h
------------------Folder4
-------------------------source4.cpp
-------------------------source4.h
-----------------Folder5
-------------------------source5.cpp
-------------------------source5.h
------------------Folder6
-------------------------source6.cpp
-------------------------source6.h
------------------Folder7
-------------------------source7.cpp
-------------------------source7.h
----------java
----------res
---CmakeLists.txt`

The folder 'mylib' is root directory of my C++ project. Any another dir inside of the root dir is a module of the C++ project. Is it possible to link all of the files (.cpp and .h files) with CmakeLists.txt? The compiling process returns me undefined reference message that means the compiler not found header file of the class.
The current content of CmakeLists.txt is:

[Click here to view content of CmakeLists.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byyRu.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show the linker error you get as well?

Comment: The linker shows me two errors. The first one is -->  "error: cannot open CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/mylib/Folder1/source1.cpp.o: No such file or directory". The second one is: "error: undefined reference to 'Protocol::Protocol(Interface&)'". The header is there but undefined appears always @Botje

Comment: Due to the way your CMakeLists.txt is structured, CMake cannot detect added / removed files. Try forcing CMake to regenerate your build files by adding an empty line to CMakeLists.txt and recompiling. That should at least get rid of the first error, and hopefully the second as well.

Comment: I do that, but the errors appears again. Any other suggestions, @Botje?

Comment: The second error might be due to a missing _definition_ for your `Protocol::Protocol` constructor, but we cannot say for sure without seeing the code.

Comment: @Botje, this code snipped is from header file:
public:
    Protocol(Interface  &pI);
 
this is from source file:
Protocol::Protocol(
    Interface &pI)
{
    this->tf = &pI;
    this->sr = 0;
    this->sq = 0;
}

Looks okay!?

Comment: That is okay. is the source file that contains the definition part of `${SOURCES}`? You can use `message(sources ${SOURCES})` in CMake to find out. (or just stick an `#error` in your source file and see if it is generated during compilation)

Comment: Yes, it is a part of ${SOURCES}. This is very strange issue, @Botje. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Nuke all CMake intermediate files and CMakeCache.txt?

Comment: How can i do that, @Botje?

Comment: Remove any build directories your IDE generated, ideally you can just click 'clean' or 'rebuild' somewhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Botje!